# Tinymce paste menu option

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using tinymce 4. When I right click in the editor in Chrome I don't see an option to paste. Is there any way to get this option? Many users aren't familiar with using Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V to paste.

e.g.
http://jsfiddle.net/kYPER/

```
<textarea id='editor-text'></textarea>
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Paste plugin for tiny mce](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x%3apaste)

Also see [TinyMCE toolbar paste button](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=28049)

From the forum :

> Control+V is a native browser command. It's the same as clicking on the browser toolbar "Edit->Paste". That is handled by the browser native code, and does not pose a problem.The paste icon on the other hand involves the underlying Javascript calling the clipboard to trigger the paste action. It's the security mechanism that prevents Javascript from accessing the clipboard.